# asp.net jquery access object in iframe in subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, cross-domain

I have 3 applications running on same server app1.corp.local, app2.corp.local, app3.corp.local

app1 opens app2.corp.local in iframe. I've set

```
<script>
document.domain = 'corp.local'
</script>
```

I want to access objects in app2.corp.local which is in iframe, from page on app1.corp.local.

Though I've set document.domain = 'corp.local' I'm getting

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://app1.corp.local" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at contents (http://app1.corp.local/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:26363)
    at Function.map (http://app1.corp.local/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:3485)
    at n.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (http://app1.corp.local/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:26452)
    at Object.success (http://app1.corp.local/App1:31:38)
    at j (http://app1.corp.local/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:26911)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://app1.corp.local/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:27724)
    at x (http://app1.corp.local/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4:11065)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://app1.corp.local/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4:14577)
```

What could be the solution to this.?

Any help would be appreciated.!!

--
Thanks

Comment: Hello... can anybody pls help...!!!